# Change question mark and variables (?id=5) in URL into slash (/5) in asp.net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, variables, url

I'm looking for a way to turn variables in a URL after the question mark into a simple notation with a slash.

For example:
I would like to make it possible to enter this link:

```
http://localhost:50830/Controller/View?Name=Test
```

in this form into the browser

```
http://localhost:50830/Controller/View/Test
```

The controller then should recognize "Test" as the Name variable. 
So basically the two links should give the same result.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, you just need to set up your routing rules to handle this.  What do you currently have for routing? (App_Start/RouteConfig.vb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a route for that.

For example:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Test",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{name}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Controller", action = "View", Name = "" }  // Parameter defaults
                );
```

Note the `Name` parameter. By default MVC routes are setup to look for `Id` parameter.

Corresponding Action:

```
public ActionResult View(string name) 
{
...
}
```

And if you're using MVC 5, you can define the routes using [Attributes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx) as well:

```
[RoutePrefix("Home")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Route("view/{name}")]
    public ActionResult View(string name) { ... }
}
```

Comment: @Bouss, it has to go in App_Start/RouteConfig.vb with the other route registrations.  You get that if you start a site from a template.  If you don't have one, there is some extra setup required.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote if you find this answer useful!